# Where to add a flag in the package.yaml?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a package.yaml file like:

```yaml
name: ...
version: ...

...

flags:
  strict: ...
    description: ...
    ...

dependencies:
  ...

...
```

Mostly typical `package.yaml` file. And one of the dependencies uses a library (so it's a transitive dependency) which has flags (one of them is `use-pkg-config` flag).

How to turn on this flag? I tried:

```yaml
pkg-config-dependencies: that-library
```

Also I tried to add a GHC option:

```
...
ghc-options:
  ...
  -fuse-pkg-config
```

and to add `flags:` section to `library:`, it seems it does not work because I see in the compilation console output:

```yaml
......... -f-use-pkg-config ....
```

and not `-fuse-pkg-config`, so I suppose it does not work. How to add a flag for such dependency (it's transitive - I don't know it matters or not) in `package.yaml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flags can be specified in project-level configuration files, `stack.yaml` or `cabal.project`.

```
-- cabal.project
package my-dependency
  flag: +use-pkg-config
```

```
# stack.yaml
flags:
  my-dependency:
    use-pkg-config: true
```

Documentation:

- cabal https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cabal-project.html#cfg-field-flags
- stack  https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#flags